# Naming object in the response of Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
const response = await Promise.all([//Promise object one], [//Promise object two])
```

the response is an array of object, if I want the response of object one I have to do response[0], can we give the response a name? If I have 4 I item I have to do response[3] to get the last response which is not elegant.

Comment: You can use the [`array destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Destructuring assignment so that the value of the array on right hand side get assigned to the individual variables on the array at the left hand side. Like an example below:

```js
const [a, b, c] = [10, 20, 30];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Thus, you can change your assignments to:

```
const [response1, response2] = await Promise.all([Promise object one], [Promise object two]);
```

Then you will be able to access the responses using the variable `response1` and `response2`.

Comment: hmmm but if `const { response1 } = something` means something is a object has a response1 property, how using `[]` is different?

Comment: You will understand that much better if you have a look at here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment